# Вместо данных выводится иероглифы - PHP

Tags: php

Собственно, массив по-своему желанию выводит мне иероглифы(проблема не в кодировке). Когда в `echo'<pre>'.$v['name'].'</pre>';`, должно выводиться Флориус. Я проверял с другими элементами массива. Выводит те же самые иероглифы(AeC�se).

```
   $oauth = $Settings['API']['oauth_token'];
    $login = $Settings['API']['user_login'];

    #Соединение с API Метрика

    $method = 'counters'; // По умолчанию(своему умолчанию).
    $request_params = array(
        "user_login" =>  $login,
        "oauth_token" => $oauth
    );
    $query = http_build_query($request_params);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/'.$method.'?'.$query);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    echo'<pre>',print_r($result,true),'</pre>';
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value[0] as $item => $v){
            echo'<pre>'.$v['name'].'</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Сам массив:

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [rows] => 1
            [counters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [code_status] => CS_OK
                            [name] => Флориус
                            [type] => simple
                            [favorite] => 0
                            [hide_address] => 0
                            [permission] => edit
                            [webvisor] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [urls] => regexp:.*
                                    [arch_enabled] => 0
                                    [arch_type] => none
                                    [load_player_type] => proxy
                                    [wv_version] => 2
                                    [allow_wv2] => 1
                                    [wv_forms] => 1
                                )

                            [code_options] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [async] => 1
                                    [informer] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [enabled] => 0
                                            [type] => ext
                                            [size] => 1
                                            [indicator] => pageviews
                                            [color_start] => FFFFFFFF
                                            [color_end] => EFEFEFFF
                                            [color_text] => 0
                                            [color_arrow] => 1
                                        )

                                    [visor] => 1
                                    [ut] => 0
                                    [track_hash] => 1
                                    [xml_site] => 0
                                    [clickmap] => 1
                                    [in_one_line] => 0
                                    [ecommerce] => 1
                                    [alternative_cdn] => 0
                                    [ecommerce_object] => dataLayer
                                )                       
                            [gdpr_agreement_accepted] => 0
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: Важно, чтобы все файлы были сохранены в одной кодировке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
Либо в .htaccess
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает. У меня везде стоит UTF-8.

Comment: В .htaccess пробывал задавать?

Comment: Попробую, но не факт, что поможет.

Comment: Нет не помогло.

Comment: $result= mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');

$result = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $result);
попробуй что-то из этого

Comment: И это не помогает

Comment: function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
     $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}

Comment: Нет, дело не в кодировке. Вар дамп, показывает NULL string(1) "A" string(1) "e" string(1) "C" string(1) "�" string(1) "s" NULL NULL string(1) "e" NULL NULL string(1) "2" string(1) "E" NULL NULL string(1) "f" NULL NULL. А должно - Флориус.

Answer (score 0):

Решении, было очень простым. У меня вместо Массива выводился STDObject. Про это я забыл. По этому решением было перевод STBObject'a в Array.